# Client not receiving message in time (TcpClient)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I have two applications that "talk" with each other by Tcp, the problem is that when I send something, the application doesn't receives it at the same time, only when he requests the second time, then 'he' receives it duplicated. For Example:

Client request connection (income string: **00200001 0050**);

Server accept connection(acknowledge) (output string: **00570002**);

The client doesn't receives the acknowledge, but when he requests connection again, it receives an output string of: **00570002 00570002** (Duplicated).

This happens in any application that connects to mine.

```
            private int listenerPort = 4545;
            private TcpListener listener;
            private TcpClient socket;

            public Communicator()
            {
                try
                {
                    this.listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), listenerPort);
                    listenerPort++;
                    listener.Start();
                    this.connectToPendingRequest();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    listener.Stop();
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Try to connect to any pending requests
            /// </summary>
            public void connectToPendingRequest()
            {
                try
                {
                    if (socket == null || !socket.Connected)
                        if (listener.Pending())
                        {
                            this.socket = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                            this.socket.NoDelay = true;
                        }
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException) { throw new Exception("Listener was not started!"); }
                catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception("Error has ocurred when connecting to device: " + ex.Message); }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Send messages to Device
            /// </summary>
            public void sendMessages(string stringMessage)
            {
                if (socket.Connected)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        byte[] outStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringMessage);
                        socket.GetStream().Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
                        socket.GetStream().Flush();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Message could not be sent.\nError: " + ex.Message);
                    }

                }
                else { throw new Exception("No device connected"); }

            }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get Message From socket
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public String getMessageFromSocket()
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];

                socket.GetStream().Read(inStream, 0, (int)socket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Message could not be read.\nError: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Am I forgetting something? Does it have a way to ensure that message has arrived ? (Guess tcp should do it but...)

Ps: I don't have issues when receiving messages.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You are not [framing your messages](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html), If you are using sockets and you do not do anything with the returned `int` from `Read` **You have a error in your program**

Comment: I bet that this stems from you ignoring the return value of `Read` - given the description of your scenario, my guess is that the first call to `Read` returns the proper size of the data received, while the second call returns zero ("connection shutdown") - but since you ignore the return value, you interpret both as "print out all the data in the buffer". But it's hard to tell if you don't post all the relevant code in the client *and* server. There's too much missing to be sure.

Comment: The problem is that the Client only receives a message when i call the method `Write()` twice, i'm receiving clients message normally (and thanks for the advice of the return value)
ps: Client application isn't mine

Answer (score 1):

1. `listenerPort++;` is not needed. Several clients can connect to same Listener on same port
2. I don't see client code here or it is entangled with server code
3. socket.GetStream().Flush() is not needed.
4. .Pending() is non-blocking so you can miss moment of connection
5. Look at [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) code samples

Comment: Also, the OP has a `10025` buffer and asks for `ReceiveBufferSize` amount of data, which is bound to cause exceptions or buffer overflow. The `10025`-sized buffer seems to be a brilliant indicator of a crappy networking tutorial...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of using the return value of Read():

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get Message From socket
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public String getMessageFromSocket()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];

            int bytesRead = socket.GetStream().Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
            return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Message could not be read.\nError: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Do not ignore, however, the great advice given to you by Scott Chamberlain.  This doesn't help you at all with the bigger problem of determining when a complete "message" has been received.